# What does "cannot have an origin property name" mean in Realm iOS

Tags: ios, realm

I'm migrating my iOS app to Realm.  I have a few too many relationships defined such as,

```
@property (nullable) RLMArray<Book> *books;
```

But I'm getting these errors.

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
 - Property 'User.books' of type 'array' cannot have an origin property name.
```

Book is also a model with a userId field. what does this error mean?  I can't find any references to it.

Comment: Can you please share your class's complete interface declaration, and any implementations of Realm's special methods (`+primaryKey`, `+requiredProperties`, `+linkingObjectsProperties`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this error indicates that you've implemented `+linkingObjectsProperties` on your class and are returning a `RLMPropertyDescriptor` for the `books` property, despite it not being an `RLMLinkingObjects` property.

Comment: This was absolutely it.  They were originally RLMLinkingObjects, but the model changed.  I forgot to remove the linkingObjectsProperties entries.